# Which logical connective is implied by a semicolon?

Tags: notation, definition, propositional-calculus, convention

In a definition

> *Definition.* Proposition P(x) holds if
>
> - A(x) is true;
> - B(x) is true.

Usually I'd expect to see "and" or "or" to connect the two statements. What does the semicolon ";" mean? Is there a convention about this?

In particular, I saw a semicolon used this way in the following definition from page 71 of *Probabilistic Graphical Models*:
[image]

Comment: Where did you find this? It's sort of unusual and what it means depends on context.

Comment: Lacking any additional context, I'd find it a huge stretch to assume it meant "or", and a much smaller stretch to assume "and". Consider: "It is raining; I am hungry." That's pretty clearly an "and", not an "or".

Comment: @MiloBrandt The context is _Probabilistic Graphical Models_ (p.71) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASgCh.png)

Comment: @MiloBrandt Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Using the punctuation this way does not seem correct, but I'm also pretty sure it means 'and'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a semicolon like this is not really proper mathematical grammar, and so it is not something you can expect to see often and there are not clear conventions for what it means.  I would expect, though, that a semicolon like this almost always means "and".  In particular, it seems quite clear that the semicolon means "and" in the example you are interested in (the second part of the definition seems to not even make sense without assuming the first part, since "no other node" seems to mean "no node other than the one referred to in the previous statement).